# How to update image in cache when image changed on server with SDWebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage library to download images from server.
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

SDWebImage not able update the cached image when image updated on server with the same url.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`SDWebImage` does some caching by default, so it would be better to use a new URL if the image changes. So, for instance, if you have control over the URL and can change it every time the image has changed, you could do that.

If that's not the case, try using `SDWebImageRefreshCached` in the `options` field in order to respect HTTP cache control headers, like this:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/olivier.poitrey/picture"]
          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar-placeholder.png"]
                   options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

See more [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#handle-image-refresh)

Comment: I have already try this code but its not updating the image. Problem is, When i update the image on the server and move back to previous screen then image is still same there after reloading table view.

Comment: You have to make sure the server is setting the right HTTP cache control headers. I just tested a sample project with a Master->Detail structure and a single cell with an image from a URL shared from dropbox, went to the details screen, changed the image on dropbox while maintaining the same name and share URL, made sure dropbox ended syncing, pressed back on the app and the image updated. Take a look at the sample project [RefreshCachedImageTest](https://github.com/Eddpt/RefreshCachedImageTest)

Comment: Yes, its working prefect for dropbox images. I think the issue is from server side. Do you any idea about the server side?

Comment: Above method worked but deprecated now current method available is this...  
[photoView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strPhoto]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]
                           options:SDWebImageRefreshCached usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

Comment: this is still not working when images changes on server url....but url is same as before the library does not detect the change in image

Answer (score 13):

**Update:** I've actually written an entire guide about cache, including cache validation https://kean.github.io/blog/image-caching

`SDWebImage` uses `NSURLCache` when you set `SDWebImageRefreshCached` option. Apple's URL loading system implements HTTP cache, including cached responses validation. HTTP cache is quite complex, however there are many beginners guides on HTTP caching:

- [How To Optimize Your Site With HTTP
  Caching](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/)
- [HTTP caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en)

Basically, the server needs to include some of HTTP cache control headers in each response. There are many different strategies that can be used to implement revalidation. You may use either `Last-Modified` or `ETag`. This way each time the client sends a request it will automatically include in your request either `Last-Modified` or `ETag` value from previously cached response. If the image hasn't change the server will respond with status code 302 (not modified) and `NSURLConnection/NSURLSession` will transparently give you a cached response from `NSURLCache`. You don't have to download the data again, buy you still need to check with the server each time you make a request.

You can also specify an expiration date using HTTP cache control. If the expiration mechanism is used, `NSURLConnection/NSURLSession` will not revalidate cached response until it is not expired.

For more info about HTTP cache control see the links above. HTTP cache is a universal cache mechanism that should be used whenever possible.

I would recommend to use [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) framework for image loading (disclaimer: writted by me). It uses `NSURLCache` by default while still having a memory cache that holds decompressed images.

Comment: on different note , as I am trying Nuke is there a way to just remove a particular image from cache and reload new ? Also A way to clear entire cache so that all images are reloaded from server ?

Answer (score 6):

**Here is a code in swift 3 to refresh cache everytime**

```
imgCardBack.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: objUserData.back_image!), placeholderImage:UIImage(named: "cardBack"), options: .refreshCached)
```

Comment: did you use latest version of SDWebImage ?

Comment: For what purpose you use this method ? because mostly use when we update any image and its url is same but image is new at that time to get new updated image we can use above method.

Comment: Yes for same purpose I have tried. But still its not working it showing old image.

Comment: Is image URL is created by backend dev?  or you pass any name for that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172153/discussion-between-hardik-t-and-the-icoder).

Comment: So you can solve this issue in other way,

You can tell him/her to add timestamp value in image URL, so every time URL is different and no need to use cache function, it will automatically updated

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4
Simply use the following function in the SDWebImage Library :

```
SDImageCache.shared().removeImage(forKey: (ImagePath), withCompletion: nil)
```

This function will delete the saved Cash in memory and Disk , after that just Upload your new Image at the same and it will work perfectly.

Comment: Note that , ImagePath is the Path you use to download your image without url headers.

Comment: How do you get the path from URL?

Comment: It works.. Image path is basically the URL of image.. and that URL is used as the key for NSCache..

Answer (score 1):

Go to the line number 176 in the file SDWebImageManager.m and change this line

```
if (options & SDWebImageRefreshCached) downloaderOptions |= SDWebImageDownloaderUseNSURLCache;
```

to below code.

```
if (options & SDWebImageRefreshCached) {
      // force progressive off if image already cached but forced refreshing
      downloaderOptions &= ~SDWebImageDownloaderProgressiveDownload;
      // remove SDWebImageDownloaderUseNSURLCache flag
      downloaderOptions &= ~SDWebImageDownloaderUseNSURLCache;
      //ignore image read from NSURLCache if image is cached but force refreshing
       downloaderOptions |= SDWebImageDownloaderIgnoreCachedResponse;
}
```

For me it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -3):

If URL is not changed there is now way for SDWebImage to know that image has been changed on the server.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The url is same when image updated on server. Problem is there, When i update the image on the server and move back to previous screen then image is still same there after reloading table view.

Comment: Yes, image is the same because it is already cached and url is not changed. So SDWebImage can't know that images was changed on the server side. Try [Edgar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28586476/4525866) solution.

Comment: Yes, thats the problem. But when i reload the tableview it should update the image.

Comment: When you reload TableView cached images are displayed, because SDWebImage cached your images internally. I mean each time you reload table view SDWebImage checks if it has cached image for particular URL and if so display it. So as long as URL is not changed image will not changed as well.

Comment: If you don't have access to the server and can't change URL when image is changed the only solution I see for now is to clear SDWebImage cache for example before reloading table view.