# SDWebImage not updating image in cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage, image-caching

I am using  [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library for handling image cache. I implemented one of its method to download image from server and populating data in `tableView`. Here is my code for downloading image and showing in `tableViewCell` 
In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I did the following code

```
[cell.profileImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

It works perfectly here. But when I updated image on server, the `tableViewCell` still shows the same image. The problem is ,its cache is not updating image. I searched with the same keywords and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586331/how-to-update-image-in-cache-when-image-changed-on-server-with-sdwebimage) question on StackOverflow. But couldn't resolve the issue. I also tried to clear memory and cache on `viewDidDisappear`

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:YES];
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache]clearMemory];
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache]clearDisk];
}
```

But its not efficient way. Is there any other way to update the cache when image on server is updated ?

Comment: do you have any means to know if the image has been updated?

Comment: Try to use this
 **[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache]imageCache clearMemory];**
**[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache]imageCache clearDisk];**

Comment: @EktaMakadiya, clearing cache will reload the data from server every time. It ignores the use of SDWebImage.

Comment: Then if your url is static then dont cache images. Reload image every time.  Because meaning of cache is to store image for future use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SDWebImageRefreshCached option to refresh concrete image, however you never know if the image was changed on the server side. So it's only your decision should you use image cache or not and when your cache should be updated.

Comment: I am already using `SDWebImageRefreshCached ` in options while downloading image. But still shows the old image.

Comment: SDWebImageRefreshCached will not ignore your cache, it only will proceed the Cache-Control http header. So server side settings can control your cache life itself. You should communicate with server admin to discuss this behaviour
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9

Comment: Thanks. I'll try discussing.

Answer (score 2):

From `SDWebImage` [docs](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#handle-image-refresh) :

> If you don't control the image server you're using, you may not be able to change the URL when its content is updated. In such case, you may use the SDWebImageRefreshCached flag. This will slightly degrade the performance but will respect the HTTP caching control headers

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                      options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

It would defeat the purpose of *Image Caching* if you use this in all your code. Coz the image will be downloaded everytime. Instead you could :

1. If you manage the server, you could setup some flags in the DB to indicate the image has changed on the server.
2. Implement some logic to only use `SDWebImageRefreshCached` once in 2 days or something like that, and use the normal code all other times.

You could also clear the entire cache once in a while to force a refresh, if that's feasible.

Comment: Clearing entire cache is not feasible. It ignores the use of SDWebImage. and as i have added code to download image from server, it includes 'SDWebImageRefreshCached` in options. But shows old image everytime.

Comment: have you tried calling that url in your browser and making sure that the image has actually changed?

Comment: Yes, It tried calling it. Also somewhere else in my app, I am downloading same image from server without using SDWebImage. Image is updated there.